# Fresh installation of McAfee ePO failing due to security certification issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, installation, mcafee

I'm trying to do a fresh install of the latest McAfee ePO server, however I keep getting the following error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T30aY.png)

I have looked at the knowledge base article [KB87731](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB87731) and applied the Windows Security Update patch as it recommended but that didn't solve the problem.

I then went through knowledge base article (kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB84628) and followed all the necessary steps for configuration 3 solution, but I still get the error message above. I have also tried updating and reinstalling the security certificates but that hasn't fixed anything.

What else can I do to get this problem resolved?

Comment: `What else can I do to get this problem resolved?` - Opening a support case with McAfee would be the ting I would do.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out what the problem was. The SQL database was not creating so I had to manually create the database. Once I did so, the installation was successful.